# LINQ: Grouping SubGroup

Tags: c#, .net, linq, igrouping, nested-groups

How to group SubGroup to create list of Continents where each Continent has it own counties and each country has its own cities like this table

[image]

Here is the t-sql:

```
select Continent.ContinentName, Country.CountryName, City.CityName 
from  Continent
left join Country
on Continent.ContinentId = Country.ContinentId

left join City
on Country.CountryId = City.CountryId
```

and the result of t-sql:

[image]

I tried this but it groups the data in wrong way i need to group exactly like the above table

```
  var Result = MyRepository.GetList<GetAllCountriesAndCities>("EXEC sp_GetAllCountriesAndCities");

    List<Continent> List = new List<Continent>();


    var GroupedCountries = (from con in Result
                             group new
                             {


                                 con.CityName,

                             }

                             by new
                             {

                                 con.ContinentName,
                                 con.CountryName
                             }

            ).ToList();

    List<Continent> List = GroupedCountries.Select(c => new Continent()
    {

        ContinentName = c.Key.ContinentName,
        Countries = c.Select(w => new Country()
        {
            CountryName = c.Key.CountryName,

            Cities = c.Select(ww => new City()
            {
                CityName = ww.CityName
            }
            ).ToList()

        }).ToList()


    }).ToList();
```

Comment: It groups in the wrong way? In what way is it wrong?

Comment: I don't even see a group by in the T-SQL.

Comment: I think you have to group again within the projection of the first groups: `Result.GroupBy(x => x.ContinentName).Select(g => g.GroupBy(x => x.CountryName))`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Yes.. i want to group like this Continent -->Country--> City

Comment: @juharr...thank you so much for your help :) . I group by linq... would it better to group by sql? if yes please write simple code to show me how can i do that...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to group everything by continent, these by country and the countries by city:

```
List<Continent> List = MyRepository.GetList<GetAllCountriesAndCities>("EXEC sp_GetAllCountriesAndCities")
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContinentName)
    .Select(g => new Continent 
    {
        ContinentName = g.Key,
        Countries = g.GroupBy(x => x.CountryName)
                     .Select(cg => new Country 
                     {
                         CountryName = cg.Key,
                         Cities = cg.GroupBy(x => x.CityName)
                                    .Select(cityG => new City { CityName = cityG.Key })
                                    .ToList()
                     })
                     .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! You are always help me my good friend!! This is exactly what i was looking for. What do you think about grouping that way with Linq, Is that fine, or should i group in sql server instead of Linq?
my another question is: I am a new developer what is your advice for me to become really professional developer like :) ?

Comment: I spent two days looking how to group that in sql server but couldn't find any helpful article

Comment: Even if you group in the database you wouldn't get your nested structure, so your current approach is fine. Another approach would be to order the result set in the database by continent, country and city. Then a simple and efficient loop would be enough to create your list.

Comment: You can start helping others in stckoverflow with things you already know. On that way you learn a lot because you have to think about this issue and you probably get other, better answers that show you different approaches. Therefore add your preferred tags to a question filter and you see new questions immediately which you might be able to answer.

Comment: Hi Tim :), Can you please help me to solve this problem? thank you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275624/entity-framework-removing-child-entity/39276333?noredirect=1#comment65887790_39276333

Answer (score 2):

You should apply grouping twice

```
var grouped = Result
    .GroupBy(x => x.CountryName)
    .GroupBy(x => x.First().ContinentName);

var final = grouped.Select(g1 => new Continent
{
    ContinentName = g1.Key,
    Countries = g1.Select(g2 => new Country
    {
        CountryName = g2.Key,
        Cities = g2.Select(x => new City { CityName = x.CityName }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much :)... But i don't understand var grouped = Result
    .GroupBy(x => x.CountryName)
    .GroupBy(x => x.First().ContinentName);

Can you please tell me an easier way to group it? something like what i used in my code... thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I wanted to mention a much easier way per microsoft that is a bit more readable. This is an example with only 2 levels though but it will most likely work for others who reach this page (like me)

```
 var queryNestedGroups =
        from con in continents
        group con by con.ContinentName into newGroup1
        from newGroup2 in
            (from con in newGroup1
             group con by con.CountryName)
        group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

The documentation for that is at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/create-a-nested-group
and is using a Student object as an example

I do want to mention that the method they use for printing is harder than just creating a quick print function on your continent object