# Entity Framework: Removing child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to remove category object from News but it doesn't work

My code looks like this:

```
var OriginalCategoriesIds = db.News.Where(w => w.NewsId == 1)
                                   .SelectMany(v => v.Categories)
                                   .ToList();
News NewsToUpdate = new News() { NewsId = 1 };
db.News.Attach(NewsToUpdate);

foreach (var category in OriginalCategoriesIds)
{
    if (!model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Contains(category.CategoryId))
    {
        NewsToUpdate.Categories.Remove(category);
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: any `errors` or `exceptions` ?

Comment: I would expect this to error out on the Remove.  You just initialized the `NewsToUpdate` variable and didn't put in any `Categories` nor initialize it, so I don't know why it would have any `Categories` to remove.

Comment: @stephen.vakil, Thank you for your help :) , Yes you are right , i am actually new to Entity Framework, Can you please tell how can i remove the categories from the association News object  without loading the news from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF should be smart enough to look at your updated entity and know which ones to remove based on which ones are present.  Instead of checking which ones don't belong anymore, check which ones do.  In theory it should properly sync up then.  Also, most likely you also want to check which ones were added that weren't there.  Instead of loading existing category ids from the news, just load all the ids that are now attached and then add them all in.

```
   News NewsToUpdate = new News() { NewsId = 1 };
   var updatedCategoryIds = model.SelectedCategoriesIds;
   NewsToUpdate.Categories.AddRange(db.Categories.Where(c => updatedCategoryIds.Contains(c.CategoryId));
   db.News.Attach(NewsToUpdate);
   db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: In what way?  Error?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your issue:

```
var OriginalCategoriesIds = db.News.Where(w => w.NewsId == 1).SelectMany(v => v.Categories).ToList();
                            News NewsToUpdate = new News() { NewsId = 1 };
                            db.News.Attach(NewsToUpdate);

                            foreach (var category in OriginalCategoriesIds)
                            {
                                if (!model.SelectedCategoriesIds.Contains(category.CategoryId))
                                {
                                    db.News.Categories.Remove(category);// <---change like this
                                }

                            }

                            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Pretty sure that will remove the item from the root categories table, not from the association of a news to a category.  I think the intent is to update the news item and update the list of categories.  Instead of removing ones that are not there, they should add ones that are still there, and then the update would remove the missing ones.

Comment: what about this `db.News.Categories.Remove(category);` @stephen.vakil

Comment: Still not accomplishing the intent, I think.

Comment: That way it will scan all Category table to add the selected ids... 
all i need is to remove associated categories from news